# Proof: $\chi'\geq\frac{e}{\alpha'}$

Tags: graph-theory

How can I proof:

In any graph with $e$ edges and edge independence number $\alpha'$, the edge coloring number $\chi'$ satisfies the inequality $\chi'\geq\frac{e}{\alpha'}$

Answer (score 1):

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph with $e$ edges, edge independence number $\alpha'$, and edge coloring number $\chi'$. Coloring the edges of $G$ with the $\chi'$ different colors induces a partition on the edge set
$$E = E_1 \sqcup E_2 \sqcup \cdots \sqcup E_{\chi'},$$
where $E_i$ is the set of edges colored with the color $i$. Since the edge independence number is $\alpha'$, we have
$$|E_i| \leq \alpha'$$
for each $i=1,\dots, \chi'$. Therefore
\begin{align*}
e = & \; |E|\\
= & \; |E_1| + |E_2| +\cdots + |E_{\chi'}|\\
\leq & \; \underbrace{\alpha'+\alpha'\cdots + \alpha'}_{\chi'}\\
= & \; \alpha' \chi',
\end{align*}
and the result follows.